# Series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}/i!$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}/i!$ is clearly convergent by the ratio test with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-i}$, but is it possible to calculate the exact sum?

Comment: $e^{1/2}-1$ is it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More generally, $$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}x^i$$
Applying this with $x=2^{-1}$ gives the series you want, but starting at $i=0$.  That is an extra $2^0/0!=1$ in the sum.  Subtract this off and you get $\sqrt{e}-1$, as @Daniel points out in the comments.